# Using proftpd, how do implement directories to show up in home folder?

Tags: ftp, proftpd

So the thing is I have setup a home directory on proftpd using GADMIN-proftpd frontend. I tried doing system links onto the setup directory however they aren't recognized as shortcuts on my android file manager (MiXplorer).

Previously I did this on Windows with Filezilla Server, having various directories listed onto my home directory.

I don't know whether I'm doing this wrong. I even tried adding additional directories thinking there would be an alias option, but nothing. New to Linux here. Any help is appreciated.

proftpd.conf

```
ServerType standalone
DefaultServer on
Umask 022
ServerName "0.0.0.0"
ServerIdent on "xv-pc"
ServerAdmin example.test@gmail.com
IdentLookups off
UseReverseDNS off
Port 980
PassivePorts 49155 65534
#MasqueradeAddress None
TimesGMT off
MaxInstances 30
MaxLoginAttempts 3
TimeoutLogin 300
TimeoutNoTransfer 120
TimeoutIdle 1200
DisplayLogin welcome.msg
DisplayChdir .message
User nobody
Group nobody
DirFakeUser off nobody
DirFakeGroup off nobody
DefaultTransferMode binary
AllowForeignAddress off
AllowRetrieveRestart on
AllowStoreRestart on
DeleteAbortedStores off
TransferRate RETR 220
TransferRate STOR 250
TransferRate STOU 250
TransferRate APPE 250
SystemLog /var/log/secure
RequireValidShell off
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
TLSEngine off
TLSRequired off
TLSVerifyClient off
TLSProtocol SSLv23
TLSLog /var/log/proftpd_tls.log
TLSRSACertificateFile /etc/gadmin-proftpd/certs/cert.pem
TLSRSACertificateKeyFile /etc/gadmin-proftpd/certs/key.pem
TLSCACertificateFile /etc/gadmin-proftpd/certs/cacert.pem
TLSRenegotiate required off
TLSOptions AllowClientRenegotiation
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
SaveRatios off
RatioFile "/restricted/proftpd_ratios"
RatioTempFile "/restricted/proftpd_ratios_temp"
CwdRatioMsg "Please upload first!"
FileRatioErrMsg "FileRatio limit exceeded, upload something first..."
ByteRatioErrMsg "ByteRatio limit exceeded, upload something first..."
LeechRatioMsg "Your ratio is unlimited."
</IfModule>
<Limit LOGIN>
  AllowUser xevile
  DenyALL
</Limit>

<Anonymous /home/xevile/ftp/home>
User xevile
Group Home
AnonRequirePassword on
MaxClients 10 "The server is full, hosting %m users"
DisplayLogin welcome.msg
DisplayChdir .msg
<Limit LOGIN>
Allow from All
Deny from all
</Limit>
AllowOverwrite on
<Limit LIST NLST  STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  RNFR RNTO  DELE  MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE  SITE_CHMOD  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit SITE_CHGRP  MTDM >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
<Directory /media/xevile/Music/Music>
AllowOverwrite off
<Limit LIST NLST  STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit RNFR RNTO  DELE  MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE  SITE_CHMOD  SITE_CHGRP  MTDM >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
</Directory>
<Directory /media/xevile/01D206B2C33F5A20/RigoR>
AllowOverwrite off
<Limit LIST NLST  STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit RNFR RNTO  DELE  MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE  SITE_CHMOD  SITE_CHGRP  MTDM >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
</Directory>
<Directory /media/xevile/Software/Torrents>
AllowOverwrite on
<Limit LIST NLST  STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  RNFR RNTO  DELE  MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE_CHMOD  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit SITE  SITE_CHGRP  MTDM >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
</Directory>
<Directory /media/xevile/Software/Software/L-pah>
AllowOverwrite on
<Limit LIST NLST  STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  RNFR RNTO  DELE  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE  SITE_CHMOD  SITE_CHGRP  MTDM >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
</Directory>
<Directory /media/xevile/Anime>
AllowOverwrite on
<Limit LIST NLST  STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  RNFR RNTO  DELE  MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE_CHMOD  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit SITE  SITE_CHGRP  MTDM >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
</Directory>
</Anonymous>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  Your question only argues that you did something and are unsure about it.

Comment: something like having directories show up on the setup home directory.

For example ftp/home/Music | ftp/home/Books

Comment: Managed to do what I wanted. Had to mount the destination onto folder for it to work.

`  sudo mount --bind /media/xevile/Music/ /var/ftp/Music `

It's working, however every restart I had to remount the directory. For the time being I'm running a script with those command on system start.